# Can't use regular expression with .*

Tags: c, regex

I've been trying to use regular expressions (`<regex.h>`) in a C project I am developing.

According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/okKv9q/1) the regex it is well written and identifies what I'm trying to identify but it doesn't work when I try to run it in C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main() {
    char pattern[] = "#include.*";
    char line[] = "#include <stdio.h>";
    
    regex_t string;
    int regex_return = -1;
    
    regex_return = regcomp(&string, line, 0);
    regex_return += regexec(&string, pattern, 0, NULL, 0);
    
    printf("%d", regex_return);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a sample code I wrote to test the expression when I found out it didn't work.

- It prints 1, when I expected 0.
- It prints 0 if I change the `line` to `"#include"`, which is just strange to me, because it's ignoring the `.*` at the end.

Comment: it seems like you should be passing `pattern` to `regcomp`, and `line` to `regexec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` and `pattern` are swapped.

`regcomp` takes the pattern and `regexec` takes the string to check.